# How to start an activity from a header button which is included in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am actually trying to open an activity from header button which is included in a fragment but unable to start. I am a beginner just trying to explore how things happens. I have search and din't found any answer hope someone can answer it. Below is my my code.
This is my header layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="@color/lightOrange">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSignInUp"
        android:text="Signin / Signup"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".AccountFragment">

    <include layout="@layout/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

This is my fragment class

```
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment {

    Button btnSignInUp;

    public AccountFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);

        //binding id for signinup button
        this.btnSignInUp=view.findViewById(R.id.btnSignInUp);

        this.btnSignInUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),SignInUpActivity.class));
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

Actually I am inflating the fragment from BottomNavigationView and from there the header layout button is suppose to open an new activity
Here is BottomNavigationVIew code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <!--serve as a container for a different fragments-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"/>
    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

When btnSignInUp is clicked all I want to open an activity called SignInUpActivity unfortunately  I am unable to open what I am missing here. Guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting an error when clicking the button?

Comment: No, no error nothing happens #yams

Comment: add a toast to your onclick method to check if the button is functioning or not .

Comment: Can you show us log when you are click on the button? That would be good to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are navigating from a fragment you may want to use Context instead of activity as noted below:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), SignInUpActivity.class));
}
```

or

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), SignInUpActivity.class));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine, as it looks like. It should work. Try, to create a Toast or a log, to test it's coming or not. If anything is not coming then, check the design, maybe your frame layout is blocking the UI.

Your code is perfectly working fine in my machine

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    initFragment()
}

private fun initFragment() {
    val fragment = MyFragment()
    val manager: FragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    val transaction: FragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "")
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
    } 
 }



public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

Button btnSignInUp;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    this.btnSignInUp = view.findViewById(R.id.btnSignInUp);

    this.btnSignInUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SignUpActivity.class));
        }
    });
    return view;
  }
}
```

Comment: He's calling a activity from a fragment not a activity.

Comment: If you want to execute a method which is present in a fragment from activity. Then, find the fragment by TAG, and call the fragment method. It will work

Answer (score 0):

It can be the case that your `findViewById` is returning null ( Although you are saying, you dont see any error ).

You can try by changing

```
this.btnSignInUp=view.findViewById(R.id.btnSignInUp);
```

1) Give Id to your included layout: So your fragment becomes :

```
<include layout="@layout/header"
android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_marginTop="45dp"/>
```

2) In your fragment code, first find the layout and then from that layout find the button:

```
LinearLayout headerLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.headerLayout);
btnSignInUp = headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnSignInUp);
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok!! Finally I have solve my problem, the thing is **headerLayout** was placed inside ScrollView which blocked my **onClickerListener** on buton **btnSignInUp**. After removing **ScrollView** It worked. Thnx everyone for your kind support.